Does the Galois group of a polynomial change upon translation?
I know that a polynomial $f(X)$ is irreducible iff $f(X+1)$ is irreducible. Is it true for the Galois group? I think it should but I don't know if there ir a neat proof (I have thought of writing the new coefficients in terms of the old ones and then applying the criteria I have seen in class). This question arises from the following question: Compute $\text{Gal}(X^4+4X^3+6X^2+4X-1/\mathbb{Q})$. All the criteria I have is for polynomials with no $X^3$ term, but for this one particullarly I thought that as $X^4+4X^3+6X^2+4X-1=(X+1)^4-2$, if the translated polynomial had the same Galois group I could easily compute it.

Yes, because the splitting fields of the polynomials will be equal. Suppose $f,g\in K[X]$ are polynomials where $f(X+1)=g(X)$. If $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$ are the roots of $f$, then $\alpha_1-1,\dots,\alpha_n-1$ are the roots of $g$. It is then clear that the splitting field of $f$ and the splitting field of $g$ are equal (i.e. $K[\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n]=K[\alpha_1-1,\dots,\alpha_n-1]$).
Since the Galois group of a polynomial is the galois group of the splitting field, $f$ and $g$ must have the same Galois gorup
